# Using CipherOutputStream + AES to write a string to a file

Tags: java, security, encryption

I'm looking for a way to, given a password of any size, encrypt a file I'm receiving over a stream with `AES`. To make things easier to start with, I was trying to just write some encrypted message to a file. But I'm having trouble:

1. I'd like to be able to define a password of any size. Is it possible to accomplish it in a "standard" form or will I have to pad the passwords to 2^k sizes? I'm currently circumventing the problem providing a temporary "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" password, but I'd like to get rid of it as soon as possible.
2. If I try to write a long string to `cos`, something encrypted will be written to the file. But if I try something smaller, as "abc", nothing will be written. I've played with several padding options but they seem of no avail (PKCS5Padding, SSL3Padding, NoPadding).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    SecretKeySpec localSecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    localCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, localSecretKeySpec);

    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("abc"), localCipher);
    IOUtils.write("abc", cos);
    cos.flush();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/992413/391315) shows how to use a `SecretKeyFactory` to generate a key based on arbitrary length passwords.

As for your second problem, `cos.flush()` is not enough to pad and encrypt the last block. You need to call `cos.close()` for that. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html#close()) is the documentation for the `close()` method which states this fact.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a cryptographic hash (e.g., SHA-1) to convert any string into a fixed-length binary value.

That's what I did in a simple file encrypter I wrote some time ago.
See the `deriveKey()` methods in:
http://david.tribble.com/src/java/tribble/crypto/FileEncrypter.java